# Is there a way to automatically add a period after two spaces in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, autocorrect

There is no easy way to implement an AutoCorrect that replaces two spaces (`"  "`) with a period and a space (`". "`) the way smart phones work.

Is there some other alternative method I could possibly implement?

The only reason I am asking is because at work while typing documents, I frequently make this mistake out of habit from typing on my iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not while you're typing, but when you get done you could do a find and replace and replace every instance of "space space" with "period space space"

Answer (score 1):

Install [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/download/)

Put this code in a text file, with extension .ahk rather than .txt, and run with AutoHotKey, either through file association or dragging the script onto the AHK executable

```
:*:  ::{NumpadDot}{space}
```

Now every time you type double space in any program, you'll get period then space instead. You can add the script to your windows start up folder if it is associated with the AHK program. You can suspend the script in the tray if you need to type double spaces for a while.

Edit:
If you have trouble with auto running the script on windows start, you could make a batch file like this (replacing the file paths of course):

```
"C:\[path]\AutoHotKey\Program\AutoHotkey.exe" "C:\Users\[path]\double space.ahk"
```